# Best way to perform mySQL queries and arrange the results

Tags: mysql

I need to be able to display the results of the below query in a specific order. For example: showing featured listings before the rest of the results.

```
WHERE IS `featured-listing` && WHERE IS NOT `featured-listing`
```

Could probably run 2 queries and a union right, bu is that the most effective solution? I know this can be done with one query I just cant remember how it/s done. Any and all help is appreciated.

```
SELECT `Assigned-Regions`,`Description`,`Category`,`Start-Date` FROM `adds` WHERE `Status` = "Active" ORDER BY `Start-Date` DESC
```

Comment: I don't understand your question, but how about `order by feature-listing, start-date desc`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a case statement for ORDER BY.

So something like 
    `SELECT ... ORDER BY (CASE WHEN featured-listing THEN 1 ELSE 2) ASC, some-other-field ASC`

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like all you need is to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your query.

If `featured-listing` column is integer datatype and contains values of 1 or 0 (1=is featured listing, 0=not a featured listing), then you could simply add something as simple as:

```
 ORDER BY `featured-listing` DESC, `Start-Date` DESC
```

Or, you could use an expression:

```
ORDER BY IF(`featured-listing`=1,1,0) DESC, `Start-Date` DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

you can do conditional ordering.. not sure what featured-listing is without seeing some data but this is the logic for conditional ordering

```
SELECT `Assigned-Regions`,`Description`,`Category`,`Start-Date` 
FROM `adds` 
WHERE `Status` = "Active" 
ORDER BY 
    CASE WHEN `featured-listing` THEN 1 ELSE 2 END ASC,
    `Start-Date` DESC
```